# Problem with formatting my f string output in Python

Tags: python, formatting, string-formatting

I am trying to get the output of my code formatted in the following way:

Expected:

```
 1 aggc tgtc aatg
13 ctag gcat agaa
25 gtcg tgct gtag
37 agat agtc tgat
49 agtc gc
```

However, I always get the following output:

```
1 aggc tgtc aatg13 ctag gcat agaa25 gtcg tgct gtag37 agat agtc tgat49 agtc gc
```

I'm not sure how to get a new line where it is supposed to be. Can someone help me with this?
Thanks a lot!

Here is my code so far that created this output (it is part of a certain function):

```
to_return += f'{str(index_row): >} {block_row}'
return to_return
```

EDIT: I came across another problem:
Does anyone know how I can align the 1 in the first row to the right? I thought that the ">" sign in my code would do the trick, but my 1 stays aligned to the left side.

Comment: Your code doesn't have any newline characters. You'd want to have a `\n` appended to the string when your row ends

Comment: Thanks for the help! Does anyone know how I can align the 1 in the first row to the right? I thought that the ">" sign in my code would do the trick, but my 1 stays aligned to the left side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the newline character (`\n`) to the end of your string:

```
to_return += f'{str(index_row): >} {block_row}\n'
return to_return
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! My code does exactly what it needs to do now.

Answer (score 2):

Add a new-line character (`\n`) at the end of the line.  Like this:

```py
to_return += f'{str(index_row): >} {block_row}'+"\n"
```